# Rust macro_rules!: How to write lifetimes?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to create a lifetime-generic function within a macro. Nothing fancy from the outside, just a hardcoded function-local one:

```rust
macro_rules! generate_parse_function {
    ($rule_name:ident, $parse_expr:tt) => {
        fn $rule_name<'a>(code: &'a str) -> (Option<Ast>, &'a str) {
            (Ast::$rule_name, $parse_expr)
        }
    };
}
```

But no matter what I do it comes out like this:

```rust
fn nil< 'a>(code: & 'astr) -> (Option<Ast>, & 'astr){
    (Ast::nil,"NIL")
}
```

There's a space before `'a` (which may or may not be a problem), and the space is removed between `a` and `str` (which is definitely a problem). I can't find anything about this on the internet, but it must be a reasonably common scenario. Anybody know what to do here?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56b1800f3b9e11fa054d80202b422e9a)—click Tools (top-right) then Expand macros and scroll the output window to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, this appears to be a bug in `rust-analyzer`. It reports the wrong result but when I run `cargo-expand` manually, I get the correct result (as pointed out by @eggyal).

Comment: Reported the bug here: https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/2765